# What were the 'philosophical cover-up' practised by Heidegger in his Nietzschean lectures 1936-45

Tags: nietzsche, heidegger

In Bambachs, *Heidegger Roots*, he offers an authoritative analysis of the manipulations practised by Heidegger in his Nietzsche lectures between 1936-45. He calls them a 'philosophical cover-up' consciously engineered by Heidegger and a 'strategy of elision and omission' and 'a self-conscious practise of political cleansing.'

**Q. What were the nature of this 'cover-up'?**

**Q. And what was Heidegger intending by it?**

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question. You may get some insight from this book at Internet Archive. "In Heidegger's Nazism and Philosophy" by philosopher Tom Rockmore. https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_ns22iU6CYTEC

Comment: I keep starting this book but I never get around to reading the whole thing, but looking at the index he does seem to discuss these Nietzsche Lectures. Correct Typo, "On Heidegger's Nazism and Philosophy" is the title.